# How to close wpf window from another project

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, projects

I have a problem here.
In project A I have a wpf, I referred the project B, and in this wpf , I create a winform b which defined in Project B.

When I closing the form b, I want to also close the wpf.

Since I already referred project B in project A. How can I close the wpf?

The code is like this:

```
using projectB;
namespace projectA    
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            function();
        }

        public void function()
        {
            form = new formb();
            form.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

.

```
namespace projectB
{       
    public partial class formb : WinFormBase
    {
        private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Dispose();
            // how to also close the wpf(MainWindow) here?
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make an object responsible for keeping track of all the windows. Make sure this object opens all windows.

Put all these windows in a list and just walk the list to close all the windows.

Using Application.Current.Shutdown might cause windows getting closed without saving state.

Try to implement a graceful shutdown.

### Alternative

Make a global event and have all the windows listen to it. When the event is raised, have each window close itself.

### Example

```
public static class WindowManager
{
    public static event EventHandler<EventArgs> ClosingWindows;

    public static void CloseWindows()
    {
        var c = ClosingWindows;
        if (c != null)
        {
            c(null, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

In each window register for this event and respond to it.
Note that you will have to decide when you call the `WindowManager.CloseWindows` method. In this example it is put in a click handler of a button but you might want to add it to other event handlers as well (what happens when the user presses Alt-F4 or clicks the red close button on the top right)

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // register for the other windows closing
        WindowManager.ClosingWindows += WindowManager_ClosingWindows;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WindowManager.CloseWindows();
    }

    void WindowManager_ClosingWindows(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // when other windows close, close this as well
        this.Close();
    }

    protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnClosed(e);

        // when closed remove eventhandler
        WindowManager.ClosingWindows -= WindowManager_ClosingWindows;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks  for respond, "Make a global event and have all the windows listen to it." sound like a good idea to organize the forms, could you please explain more specifically? 
For the easiest way, all the data have been saved before btnClose_Click, so shutdown should be no harm I guess. But where could I use it? For now, the program looks like hung there after
this.Dispose();

Comment: Do not use `this.Dispose()`. Just use `this.Close()` I'll add an example of the event later today

Comment: Hey Erno，I've learned from you, and it works like a charm. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Referring to the application as "the WPF" is a bit confusing.

To close the window, simply call `Shutdown` on the `Application`

```
Application.Current.Shutdown();
```

Comment: Thanks for respond, I mean the wpf form when I say "the WPF", sorry about that. 
Why I don't have the Application.Current.Shutdown() function or I should I use it?